# PHP MYSQLI Unable to delete a row of data from database

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli

i want to delete a row of data for example userid number 4 when i click on the delete button but nothing happen.It just pop out "Are you sure you want to delete '4undefine"  Can someone help?

index.php

```
<?php
  $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","userdatabase");
  mysqli_select_db($connection, "userdatabase");
  $sql_query="SELECT * FROM user";
  $result_set=mysqli_query($connection,$sql_query);
  if(isset($_GET['delete_id']))
  {
    $sql_query="DELETE FROM user WHERE userid=".$_GET['delete_id'];
    mysqli_query($sql_query);
    header("Location: $_SERVER[PHP_SELF]");
  }
?>
```

This is the confirmation

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function delete_id(userid,username,password,email,workplace,role)
{
  if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete '" +userid+username))
  {
    window.location.href='adminhome.php?delete_id='+userid;
  }
}
</script>




<?php
 if(mysqli_num_rows($result_set)>0)
 {
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result_set))
    {
        $userid = $row[0];
        $username = $row[1];
        $password = $row[2];
        $email = $row[3];
        $workplace = $row[4];
        $role = $row[5];
        ?>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $userid; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $username; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $password; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $email; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $workplace; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $role; ?></td>

        <td align="center"><a href="javascript:delete_id(<?php echo $row[0]; ?>)"><img src="RemoveUser.png" alt="Delete" /></a></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
  }
```

Comment: Look at this very closely `mysqli_query($sql_query);` what's different from your other query? *Teach a person HOW to fish*, I always say. One thing wrong with it. So once you fix that JS, that query won't delete without one important bit.

Comment: where you are passing another paramerters username,password,email,workplace,role? It's javascript problem use browser inspector to solve it.

Comment: for username so it is get as 4 undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your first problem is that you've defined your function like this:

```
function delete_id(userid,username,password,email,workplace,role)
```

But are calling it like this:

```
delete_id(<?php echo $row[0]; ?>)
```

Is it any wonder that `username` is undefined? Then your syntax is incorrect on your call to `mysqli_query()`, as pointed out in the comments above. [It takes two parameters](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) in the procedural style you're using.

Next thing you need to worry about is what would happen if someone went to http://your.site/adminhome.php?delete_id=4%20or%201=1. I suggest you learn about [preventing SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) ASAP.

Comment: after i changed to $sql_query=mysqli_query($connection,"DELETE FROM user WHERE userid=".$_GET['delete_id']); it works!  i do really appreciate all the comments and suggestion above!